# Files not loading after not changing anything

Tags: r, list, csv, file

I'm importing some files with list.files and then loading into a dataframe. After having changed nothing in my code, the files are not being imported correctly. What could be the reason for this? The files to be imported were not changed either and remain in the correct path.

```
library(data.table)
library(tidyverse)
library(stringi)

#Import files to file list
files <- list.files(path = "R/win-library/Practice/Testrun",
                    full.names = TRUE,
                    pattern="*.csv",
                    all.files = FALSE,
                    recursive = TRUE)


#Subset Files and remove Directories
files <- files[!file.info(files)$isdir]


#Read files into df "data" with path and file_name columns
data <- rbindlist(lapply(files,
                         function(x) {
                           data <- read_csv2(x)
                           data$File_name <- basename(x)
                           data$Path <- dirname(x)
                           data
                         }))
```

DF "data" is empty after running this code.
Even when running only the list.files portion of the script, the list is empty.

Comment: Hey @Aarón Gzz, `list.files` returns an empty character vector if the specified path is empty or does not exist. You mention that the folder is still in order, but to be sure you could try and verify that the path you provide actually exists (i.e. `dir.exists("R/win-library/Practice/Testrun")`). Sorry if stating the obvious!

Comment: I get TRUE when checking

Comment: In that case perhaps one of the additional arguments you provide to `list.files` leads to the null return. Have you tried just running `list.files("R/win-library/Practice/Testrun")` for starters?

Comment: just tried it and I discovered that my pattern was wrong all along. The weird thing is that when I first tried to revert to the original working pattern, it didn't solve anything back then. Now it did! Thanks. Got my pattern fixed